# Chasing the car

Tags: code-golf, math

Imagine you are sitting at a park. Suddenly your car gets hijacked and being driven in different directions. Here are the directions, arrows show which direction goes towards where:

```
     South
       |
       V
East->   <-West
       ^
       | 
     North
```

After being driven, the car stops. Now you have to find out how far the car is away from you and angle of you and your car in degrees. It will be given how many units have been driven and in which direction. Input/Output format is flexible, you can take a 2D list/1D list/string etc and return the displacement and angle.

**Test Cases**

```
[[40,East],[40,North],[30,West],[30,South]] -> 14.1421356237 45.0
[[45,North],[200,East]] -> 205.0 75.9637565321
```

No need to output exact angle and distance, just 2 digits after decimal is fine, but more than 2 is fine too.

Only given directions are North, east, south, west.

The value of movement in a direction is always positive integer.

Trailing Whitespace allowed. Code golf, so shortest code wins.

*My English is bad, sorry. Please ask for clarification if you have trouble understand ing*

Comment: I was going to say this feels like a dupe until I noticed 1. the angle output and 2. I can't seem to find the question I feel like it has to be a dupe of. Must the directions be taken as the exact strings `"North"`, `"South"`, `"East"`, `"West"`, or can they be substituted for, say, `NSEW`, consistent capitalization variants, or simply `1234`? I can't see any other issues myself at the moment, but in the future remember to give your challenges some time in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=active).

Comment: And yes, I would highly recommend you start posting your challenge ideas to the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140) first to get feedback

Comment: Is the angle in radians also ok?

Comment: @pxeger choosing 4 distinct values is probably too much (what if these 4 values are `(1, 0), (-1, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1)`?)

Comment: @pxeger you can take anything in place of directions

Comment: @GB angle must be in degrees

Comment: Where is the angle measured from? From north, like a bearing? From east, like in most maths? Can we choose?

Comment: @pxeger yes up to you

Comment: @BadCoder requiring an output format (degrees) like that is really not a good idea and [strongly discouraged on this site](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077). It adds significant byte overhead on boring I/O boilerplate instead of solving the challenge

Comment: Can you explain the number `75.9637565321`?

Comment: Can we take the input as single complex numbers, e.g. `[40+0i, 0+40i, -30+0i, 0-30i]`?

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 44 bytes

```ruby
->l{z=l.sum{|a,b|a*b};[z.abs,z.arg*57.2958]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6nuso2R6@4NLe6JlEnqSZRK6nWOrpKLzGpWAdIFqVrmZrrGVmaWsTW/i9QSIuOjjYx0DGM1QFTmUDa2EBH1xBGZ8bGxnJBlZmClRkZgNXFxv4HAA)

Input direction as:

- 1i East
- 1 North
- -1i West
- -1 South

Comment: Since "just 2 digits after decimal is fine", you can probably get away with changing `Math::PI` to just `3.142` or similar

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 77 bytes

```
lambda a:(abs(v:=(sum(x*d for x,d in a))),phase(v)*180/pi)
from cmath import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NcxNCoJAGMbxfad4270jIym1EMEjeAJz8ZoOjjgfjKPYWdoIUVfoLN4mSVr9Fs_D__G2d98avTxFdn2NXoTJmvekqpqAUqRqwCnNcBgVzkENwjiYeQ1SAzHGuG1paHBiQZxEJyvZQTij4KbItyCVNc4He_RjndQeBTYT9Si1HT1uAbavy3osikvE45L_6DbPEQ_jv11Z7s8v)

Takes the direction as a complex number: `1`, `-1`, `1j`, or `-1j` for east, west, north, and south respectively.

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 74 bytes

Thanks to @xnor

```
from cmath import*
m,t=polar(sum(x*d for x,d in input()))
print m,t*180/pi
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728oLIkIz_PaMGCpaUlaboWN73SivJzFZJzE0syFDJzC_KLSrS4cnVKbAvycxKLNIpLczUqtFIU0vKLFCp0UhQy84CooLREQ1NTk6ugKDOvRAGoWMvQwkC_IBNiItTgBTcVo6NNDHQMY3XAVBaQNjbQ0TWE0VmxsRCVAA)

Full program taking input as a list from STDIN with directions as above.

Comment: Oh nice ATO in action

Comment: `cmath` has `polar` which gives `(abs(v), phase(v))`, though you'd have to find a way to convert the angle to degrees

Comment: @xnor check back in the revision history: I used that until OP mentioned that degrees were required, but I couldn't find a shorter way of doing it with `polar` (although there's [this](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728oLIkIz_PaMGCpaUlaboWN31TUtMU0jQSNa1ydUpsC_JzEos0iktzNSq0UhTS8osUKnRSFDLzFBI1Na0LijLzShSAyrQMLQz0CzK50orycxWScxNLMhQycwvyi0q0IIauStPIzCsoLdHQ1IQILLipGB1tYqBjGKsDprKAtLGBjq4hjM6KjYWoBAA) in Python 2 for =77)

Comment: @pxeger For the python 2, it looks like you can save a few bytes with a program taking `input`.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 18 bytes

Anonymous tacit infix function, taking a list of complex units as one argument and the magnitudes as another argument.

```apl
(|,{180÷○÷12○⍵})+.×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X6NGp9rQwuDw9kfTuw9vNzQCUo96t9Zqauv/T3vUNuFRb9@jruZHvWse9W45tN74UdvER31Tg4OcgWSIh2fw/zQFEwMvAwUDLxMDBaA8hA1icKWBBE0VjAyAYgA)

`+.×` dot product, i.e. sum of products of directions and magnitudes

`(`…`)` apply the following tacit function to that:

`{`…`}` apply the following lambda to that; `⍵` is the argument:

`12○⍵` the phase (i.e. angle)

`÷` reciprocal of that

`○` *π* times that

`180÷` 180 divided by that

`|,` prepend the absolute value

---

If we were allowed to answer in radians, the solution would be just:

```apl
10 12○+.×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///39BAwdDo0fRubb3D0/@nPWqb8Ki371FX86PeNY96txxab/yobeKjvqnBQc5AMsTDM/i/iYECEBmDUZqCoZeBgoGXocKh9RAWkOYyMVUwMgBJgiSAwgA)

`+.×` dot product, i.e. sum of products of directions and magnitudes

`10 12○` magnitude and phase of that

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 115 bytes

```python
x=y=0;from math import*
for u,d in input():exec('x+=u y+=u x-=u y-=u'.split()[d])
print hypot(x,y),atan(x/y)*180/pi
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYrBCsMgEAXv@Yq9RVPbmKSH0pIvCR5Ck6BQdbEr6NdbQ@ExM4eHmbR3YylpzrN8HcFbsCtpMBZ9oK45fIAoNjCuDiMx/tzT/mZtuswR8ol0PauivX3xY@pl2RRvMBhHoDN6YklkLlZaHUt95t3wkD2aUpblLoVU4tRQNUkx/jUp9QM)

Straightforward approach. Full program. Takes input as a 2D list, 0 for East, 1 for North, 2 for West, 3 for South.

Comment: Imagine having a functional atan...

Comment: @AUsername feels nice to have mathematical functions direct in programming

Comment: Sadly mine'll be non-competing :p